Norm $\text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(\pi_L)$ of Uniformizer of finite extension of $p$-adics
Let $ K/ \Bbb Q_p$ a finite extension of $p$-adic field $\Bbb Q_p$ of degree $[K:\Bbb Q_p]=n$ and let $ \pi_L$ be a uniformizer of $L$.
Question: Can we say something interesting / "distinguished" about structure of the norm $\text{Norm}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(\pi_L)$ of the uniformizer?
Does it have some interesting properties with respect to underlying Galois action, with respect the ring structure of $\Bbb Z_p$ (...eg relation with the power $(p)^d$ where it lands) one should keep in mind deling with structure theory of extension of non archimedian local fields?
Vague "motivation" for the vague question: as a uniformizer is (up to mult. with unit) ring theoretically a "distinguished" object, it seems to me that it is reasonable to expect something "interesting" aout it's norm.
By definition $\text{Norm}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(\pi_L)= \prod_{g \in G} g(\pi_L)$, so it lands rougly in $(p) \cap \mathfrak{p}_L^n$ as norm maps ideals to ideals and Galois action preserves the maximal ideal.
But is it in general what we can say about the properties of $\text{Norm}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(\pi_L)$ or are there more interesting features?

You write $\prod_{g \in G} g(\pi_L)$ but never say what $G$ is. You presumably mean a Galois group, but (i) you never said $L/\mathbf Q_p$ is Galois and (ii) the norm ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p} : L \to \mathbf Q_p$ makes sense for all finite extensions, whether or not they are Galois.  I personally think it's best to define the norm map on field extensions without  using field automorphisms or field embeddings: ${\rm N}_{L/K}(\alpha) = \det(m_\alpha)$, where $m_\alpha : L \to L$ is multiplication by $\alpha$ on $L$, viewed as a $K$-linear map.
Let $n  = [L:\mathbf Q_p]$, $e = e(L/\mathbf Q_p)$, and $f = f(L/\mathbf Q_p)$. We have $|\pi_L|_p = (1/p)^{1/e}$ and $|\pi_L|_p = \sqrt[n]{|{\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)|_p}$,  so $|{\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)|_p = |\pi_L|_p^n = (1/p)^{n/e} = (1/p)^f = 1/p^f = 1/q_L$, where $q_L = |\mathcal O_L/(\pi_L)|$ is the size of the residue field of $L$. For example, ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)$ is a prime in $\mathbf Z_p$ if and only if $f = 1$, meaning that $L/\mathbf Q_p$ is totally ramified.
Writing $L^\times = \pi_L^{\mathbf Z} \times \mathcal O_L^\times$, we have ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(L^\times) = {\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)^{\mathbf Z} \times {\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$.  Let $A$ be the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ in $L$.
By local class field theory we have the non-obvious equation ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(L^\times)= {\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(A^\times)$, so
$$
{\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)^{\mathbf Z} \times {\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_L^\times) = {\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_A)^{\mathbf Z} \times {\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_A^\times).
$$
Looking at the elements of absolute value $1$ on both sides, we get
${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_L^\times) = {\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_A^\times)$ in $\mathbf Z_p^\times$. Call that common norm-unit group $U$, so ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)^{\mathbf Z} \times U = {\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_A)^{\mathbf Z} \times U$.
Since $|{\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)|_p < 1$ and $|{\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_A)|_p < 1$, the norms ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)$ and
${\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_A)$ are unit multiples, so $|{\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)|_p = |{\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_A)|_p$, so $1/q_L = 1/q_A$: $L$ and the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ in $L$ have the same residue fields, so $f(L/\mathbf Q_p) = f(A/\mathbf Q_p)$.
A uniformizer in $L$ is only determined up to unit multiple, so the set of norms of all possible uniformizers in $L$ is ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)U$, which equals ${\rm N}_{A/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_A)U$.  Thus all $L$ with the same maximal abelian extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ in them have the same set of norms of all uniformizers. In other words, the set of norms of all possible uniformizers in $L$ is completely determined by $A$, and $A$  could be the same field for many different $L$.
For example, when the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ in $L$ is $\mathbf Q_p$ (that is, $A = \mathbf Q_p$), we have $U = \mathbf Z_p^\times$ and the set of norms of all possible uniformizers in $L$ is $p\mathbf Z_p^\times$. An example of such an $L$ is $L = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p})$ where $(m,p(p-1)) = 1$. Here's why:  $[L:\mathbf Q_p] = m$ since $x^m - p$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q_p$, so if we show all $m$th roots of unity in $L$ are in $\mathbf Q_p$, then the only fields between $L = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p})$ and $\mathbf Q_p$ are the fields $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})$ where $d \mid m$ by Theorem 5.2 here, and to have $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})/\mathbf Q_p$ be abelian requires $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_d) \subset \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})$, which implies $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_d) = \mathbf Q_p$ because $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})/\mathbf Q_p$ is totally ramified while $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_d)/\mathbf Q_p$ is unramified due to $d\mid m$ and $p \nmid m$. The prime-to-$p$ roots of unity in $\mathbf Q_p$ have order dividing $p-1$ (this includes the case $p=2$, when $\mathbf Q_p$ has a root of unity with order $p$), so $d\mid (p-1)$ and thus $d = 1$ since $d \mid m$ and $(m,p-1)=1$. That shows $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})/\mathbf Q_p$ with $d \mid m$ is abelian only when $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p}) = \mathbf Q_p$, which is what we wanted.  The only missing detail is showing all  $m$th roots of unity in $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p})$ must be in $\mathbf Q_p$, and we'll show that next.
If $L = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p})$ contains an $m$th root of unity $\zeta$ then $L$ contains $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta)$, which is unramified  over $\mathbf Q_p$ since $\zeta$ has order relatively prime to $p$, and $L/\mathbf Q_p$ being totally ramified implies the only intermediate unramified extension is $\mathbf Q_p$, so $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta) = \mathbf Q_p$. Thus $\zeta \in \mathbf Q_p$.

a sidenote: You mentioned the norm-unit group $U:= {\rm N}{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$. Assume $L \mathbf Q_p$ is Abelian extension, then there exist a so called multiplicative conductor of this extension defined as $(p)^{\mathfrak{f}}$ where $\mathfrak{f}$ is the smallest number such that $U^{\mathfrak{f}} := 1+(p)^{\mathfrak{f}}$ is contained in  the norm-unit group $U:= {\rm N}{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$ (so far I know in literature it is defined as before but subjected to condition similar as before but included in ${\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(L^{\times})$ instead,

but (correct me if that's wrong) the part $ {\rm N}{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\pi_L)^{\mathbf Z}$ not matters for this inclusion, so $U^{\mathfrak{f}}$ is contained in $ {\rm N}{L/\mathbf Q_p}(\mathcal O_L^\times)$ iff contained in $ {\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(L^{\times})$.

Do you know how to give (a rather weak) upper bound for $\mathfrak{f}$  by $p^{v_p(n)+2}$? This is remarked here
but I'm not sure how to obtain it. Obviously it would suffice to show that $1+p^{p^{v_p(n)+2}}$ is contained in image of $U$. My guess would to try with some $ {\rm N}_{L/\mathbf Q_p}(1+p^i)= (1+p^i)^n= 1+np^i +r$ with "higher terms" from the "rest" $r$, but I don't know to equalize this $r$ within $U$. Do you have an idea how to obtain this bound?

This is not about abelian extensions. An easy way that something is a norm from an extension of degree $n$ is for it be an $n$th power. So for each $n\geq 1$ you want an $r$ such that $1+p^r\mathbf Z_p \subset (1+p\mathbf Z_p)^n$. Write $n=p^km$ where $p$ doesn't divide $m$. By Hensel's lemma we have $(1+p\mathbf Z_p)^m=1+p\mathbf Z_p$, so $(1+p\mathbf Z_p)^n=(1+p\mathbf Z_p)^{p^k}$. Show when $p>2$ and $i\geq 1$ that $(1+p^i\mathbf Z_p)^p=1+p^{i+1}\mathbf Z_p$, while $(1+2^i\mathbf Z_2)^2 = 1+2^{i+1}\mathbf Z_2$ when $i \geq 2$. Then $(1+p\mathbf Z_p)^{p^k} = 1+p^{k+1}\mathbf Z_p$ if $p>2$.

And when $k \geq 1$, $(1+2\mathbf Z_2)^{2^k} = 1+2^{k+2}\mathbf Z_2$ . Thus $1+p^{k+1}\mathbf Z_p = (1+p\mathbf Z_p)^{p^k}$ when $p > 2$ and $k \geq 0$ (check $k = 0$ separately), while $1+2^{k+2}\mathbf Z_2 \subset (1+2\mathbf Z_2)^{2^k}$  when $k \geq 0$; there is equality when $k \geq 1$ but only a containment when $k = 0$.  To have a single statement applicable to all $p$, $1+p^{k+2}\mathbf Z_p \subset (1+p\mathbf Z_p)^{p^k}$ when $k \geq 0$, but we only need to use $k+2$ in the exponent because of $p = 2$. When $p > 2$ we can use $k+1$ in the exponent.

the only part that seemingly requires some effort is the inclusion $(1+p^i\mathbf Z_p)^p \supset 1+p^{i+1}\mathbf Z_p$. Say $1+p^{i+1}\cdot a$ is an element on rhs.Do I assume correctly that the idea is to make a general ansatz $1+ p^i(\sum r_j p^j)$ with $r_j$ to determine and to check forming a tower of compatible $p^j$-levelwise congruence relations are fulfillable and check that it converges (...so strategy similar to proof of Hensel's lemma)? That's the idea, right?

You could try that.  Personally I think it is more efficient to use the $p$-adic exponential, which is an isometry on its disc of convergence in $\mathbf Q_p$.

I would like to clarify how we can obtain the desired inclusion $(1+p^i\mathbf Z_p)^p \supset 1+p^{i+1}\mathbf Z_p$ using the exponential map argument you suggested. Could you skim over if I understood it correctly? So we have this iso $exp: D \to 1+D$ on its radius of convergence $D$ with inverse given by log. For our purposes it suffice to restrict it to $p^i \Bbb Z_p  \to 1+p^i \Bbb Z_p$. If we start with some $z \in (1+p^{i+1}\mathbf Z_p) $, then  $log$ maps it to $p^{i+1}\mathbf Z_p$, so we can express it as $p \cdot z' $ with $ z' \in p^{i}\mathbf Z_p$.

Now applying exp to it and observing that as in classical case exp turns sums to factors, we get $z = exp(log(z)) =exp(p \cdot z')= exp(z)^p$ and we done. So that exp is not just an group isomorphism, but even an isometry goes in here to assure that is respects the filtration by $p^i$ on both sides, that's the point, right?

Yes. And both exp and log are isometries.

typo: the last term in the sequence of equalities should be of course $exp(z')^p$

Could you sketch the argument why in the example above extension $L = \mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p})/ \Bbb Q_p$ ( where $( m, p(p-1))=1$; I guess this condition is to avoid that it falls in Kummer theory setting) has as maximal Abelian ext the trivial extension?

I updated the end of my answer to give that argument.  The key point is the linked theorem giving a simple necessary condition for intermediate fields in  $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p})/\mathbf Q_p$ all being $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})$ where $d \mid m$.

Why for such intermediate extension $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})/ \mathbf Q_p$ to be actually abelian it is neccassary that it contains $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_d)$ as subfield?

I leave that as an exercise in Galois theory.

Will try, but just to estimate the "neccessary tools" to deduce it, is this really just reflection/ joga on the Galois corresp on say "basic level" or does it somewhere require to invoke local Weber as "deeper tool" which says that for finite abelian ext $K/ \Bbb Q_p $ is contained in some $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_m)$ for appropr $m$ ( if remember correctly, $m$ is "controlled" by local conductor)

think it's simpler then I thought, but isn't already the assumption that $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})/ \mathbf Q_p$ Galois suffice to conclude that it contains $\zeta_d$? In other words, abelian assumption would be redundant? (Because Galois, $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})/ \mathbf Q_p$ contains all the roots $\sqrt[d]{p} \cdot \zeta_d^k, k=0,1,..., d-1$ (as $X^d-p$ irred by Eisenstein), so we can extract $\zeta_d$ by dividing out $\sqrt[d]{p} $. So, I not see where we need the abelian assumpion, seemingly Galois suffice, as it seems if my argument has no gaps that only normality of the extsn matters

That's right, it's just a consequence of being Galois. I did not want to say that right away because when trying to solve a problem you may wind up needing only something weaker than the condition you think you will need, and that is something best learned by just trying to answer your own question. We don't always discover the right minimal hypotheses before solving the problem and then looking back to see what was essential.

Do you maybe know if there are criteria generalizing this feature, namely letsome $L/K$ finite degree $d=[L:K]$ Galois ext'n of $p$-adic fields (ie in sense $L,K$ are finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$) with $(d,p^k-1)=1$ where $p^k$ cardinality of resid field of $K$, the question is it possible to chracterize when $L$ contains actually $\zeta_d$? Above we where "lucky" as we had perfect control over structure of roots as the minpol $X^d-p$ was of rather specific shape, here I discard the

knowledge about explicit structure of min polynom. HereI opened a new question adressing this, could you on occasion skim through if there some results in this direction known?
